# Beginner scheme how to replace a string into a list?

Tags: scheme, racket

;; An association list (al) is either

;; empty or

;; (cons (list k v) alst), where

;;  k is a nat (the key),

;;  v is a string (the value), and

;;  alst is an association list (al)

updatestring takes an association list, a number (findnum) and a string (newstring) and if there is a number the same as findnum in the association list, then it replaces the string in the list with newstring.

```
(check-expect(updatestring empty 3 "hi") (list (list 3 "hi")))
(check-expect(updatestring (list (list 1 "hi")(list 5 "wow")) 5 "new")(list (list 1 "hi")(list 5 "new")))
(check-expect(updatestring (list (list 1 "hi")(list 5 "wow")) 2 "nice")(list (list 2 "nice") (list 1 "hi")(list 5 "wow")))
```

I'm having trouble with the code as this is what I have.

```
(define (al-update alst akey avalue)
 (cond
  [(empty? alst) (list (list akey avalue))]
  [(= (first(first alst)) akey) (al-update (rest alst) akey avalue)]
  [else (list(list akey avalue alst))]))
```

The problem is that my code returns

```
(list (list 5 "new" (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow"))) instead of (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "new"))
```

and

```
(list(list 2 "nice" (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")))) instead of (list (list 2 "nice") (list 1 "hi")(list 5 "wow")))
```

Any tips and answers would be very much appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive structure needs to be something like this:

```
(define (al-update alist akey avalue)
  (if (empty? alist)                                 ; base, end recusion
      '()
       (cons (let ((key+value (first alist)))        ; element, one-by-one
               (if (= ...)
                    ...
                    ...))
             (al-update (rest alist) akey avalue)))) ; recursion
```

In your code there are a number of problems.  The `else` clause needs to recurse over the rest of the list.  In the `=` clause you need to do the substitution and recurse.  In my code above, I combined the two clauses that recurse.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't learned cdr or car or null? so I can't use them in my code. Is there another way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: i can use cons but not push

Comment: I don't quite understand this line (cons (let ((key+value (first alist)))

Comment: Cons takes two arguments; the second is a list, the first is something to add to the list.  In this case, the result of the `let` is added to the list.  The result of the `let` is the result of the `if` which is one of two things.  If (= ...) [you provide ...] is true then you want to substitute `avalue`, if false, then you want to use the old value.  The identifier `key+value` is just a fancy Scheme symbol; it represents the first element in `alist`.

Answer (score 0):

It says "if there is a number the same as findnum in the association list, then it replaces the string in the list with newstring", but in your example if the given number does not exist you add that into the list.

```
(check-expect (updatestring (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")) 2 "nice")
              (list (list 2 "nice") (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")))
(check-expect(updatestring empty 3 "hi") (list (list 3 "hi")))
```

Code and the examples (tests) should be these:

```
(define (al-update alst akey avalue)
 (cond
  [(empty? alst) empty]
  [(= (first (first alst)) akey) (cons (list (first (first alst)) avalue)
                                       (al-update (rest alst) akey avalue))]
  [else (cons (first alst) (al-update (rest alst) akey avalue))]))


(check-expect (updatestring empty 3 "hi") empty)
(check-expect (updatestring (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")) 5 "new")
              (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "new")))
(check-expect (updatestring (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")) 2 "nice")
              (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow")))
(check-expect (updatestring (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow") (list 2 "bad")) 2 "nice")
              (list (list 1 "hi") (list 5 "wow") (list 2 "nice")))
```

By the way "car" is equivalent to "first" and "cdr" is "rest".